# define four integers and convert it into bytes

Tags: java

How I can define four natural numbers from the range [0, 255] and representing components of a color: α, red, green, blue. Then pack these four numbers into
one int, bytes of which (from the most to the least significant) correspond to the four
components of the color in the order given above.
Using only this integer, unpack it to four numbers corresponding to the four components of the color.

For example it has to print something like this

```
a, r, g, b = 23, 121, 255, 130
color = 393871234
a, r, g, b = 23, 121, 255, 130
```

So what should I change?

```
public class ColorBytes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a = 23, r = 121, g = 255, b = 130, color = 0;
// pack four components into one int color
//
// ...
//
System.out.println("a, r, g, b = " + a +
", " + r + ", " + g + ", " + b);
System.out.println("color = " + color);
a = r = g = b = 0;
// unpack color to get its four
// components back in a, r, g, b
//
// ...
//
System.out.println("a, r, g, b = " + a +
", " + r + ", " + g + ", " + b);
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use bitwise operators.

```java
public class ColorBytes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 23, r = 121, g = 255, b = 130, color = 0;
        // pack four components into one int color
        color = a;
        color <<= 8;
        color += r;
        color <<= 8;
        color += g;
        color <<= 8;
        color += b;
        //
        System.out.println("a, r, g, b = " + a + ", " + r + ", " + g + ", " + b);
        System.out.println("color = " + color);
        a = r = g = b = 0;
        // unpack color to get its four
        // components back in a, r, g, b
        b = color & 0xFF;
        g = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
        r = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
        a = (color >> 24) & 0xFF;
        //
        System.out.println("a, r, g, b = " + a + ", " + r + ", " + g + ", " + b);
    }
}
```

To pack `color` we do the following.

1. We add the value of `a` to `color`.
2. We shift the value of `color` 8 bits to the left.
3. We add the value of `r` to `color`.
4. We shift the new value of `color` 8 bits to the left.
5. We add the value of `g` to `color`.
6. We shift the new value of `color` 8 bits to the left.
7. Finally, we add the value of `b` to `color`.

To unpack `color` we do the following.

1. Mask out the last 8 bits of `color` to get the value of `b`.
2. Shift the value of `color` 8 bits to the right and mask out the last 8 bits of the new value of `color` to get the value of `g`.
3. Shift the value of `color` 16 bits to the right and mask out the last 8 bits to get the value of `r`.
4. Shift the value of `color` 24 bits to the right and mask out the last 8 bits to get the value of `a`.

Refer to [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) in Oracle's Java tutorials.

Here is the output when the above code is run:

```
a, r, g, b = 23, 121, 255, 130
color = 393871234
a, r, g, b = 23, 121, 255, 130
```